# google charts - data from csv - date format

Tags: charts, google-visualization

In a webpage I load data from a csv file that contains like (it can contains months of data) :

```
timestamp,open,high,low,close 

2022-08-03,1.01554,1.02105,1.01210,1.01618 

2022-08-02,1.02578,1.02939,1.01619,1.01625 

2022-08-01,1.02182,1.02753,1.02040,1.02587 

2022-07-29,1.01952,1.02544,1.01440,1.02248 

2022-07-28,1.02005,1.02344,1.01120,1.01947 

2022-07-27,1.01174,1.02209,1.00950,1.01998 

2022-07-26,1.02210,1.02502,1.01060,1.01179 

2022-07-25,1.02174,1.02579,1.01770,1.02200
```

The first column is a date, but I think the google chart treat it like a string while creating the chart.

This is the  code in html page I use to load data from csv and to create the chart:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.csv-0.71.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>


<script>
// load the visualization library from Google and set a listener
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
</script>

<script>
function drawVisualization() {
   $.get("EURUSD.csv", function(csvString) {
      // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
      var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

      // this new DataTable object holds all the data
      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      //view.setColumns([0,1]);


        var options = {
          legend: 'none',
          title: 'EURUSD',
          bar: { groupWidth: '100%' }, // Remove space between bars.
          candlestick: {
            fallingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#a52714' }, // red
            risingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#0f9d58' }   // green
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        data.sort({column: 0, asc: true});
        chart.draw(data, options);

   });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization)
</script>

 <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

enter code here
```

The chart I get is:

[image]

I would like to group by month or by year in the X asses, insted of everyday date printed there.

How can I do?

Thank You

Carlo

Answer (score 0):

after you load the csv data...

```
  var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
```

convert the first column to a date...

```
  arrayData = arrayData.map(function (row) {
    row[0] = new Date(row[0]);
    return row;
  });
```